# adjust AppCompatEditText style

Tags: android, android-edittext, styles

I have a CustomEditText extends EmojiEditText which extends AppCompatEditText and deriving https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji library.

I used to ComposeEditText style for CustomEditText. But if I add this style, app is crashing. Please help me.

My edittext style:

```
        <style name="ComposeEditText" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
        <item name="android:padding">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">4</item>
        <item name="android:maxLength">2000</item>
        <item name="android:capitalize">sentences</item>
        <item name="android:autoText">true</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:imeOptions">flagNoEnterAction</item>
        <item name="android:inputType">textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|textMultiLine</item>
        </style>
```

My edittext in xml:

```
         <com.android.android.util.view.CustomEditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            style="@style/ComposeEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            app:emojiSize="@dimen/emojiSize" />
```

in code:

```
public class CustomEditText extends EmojiEditText {

    public CustomEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
    }
}
```

Error log:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
        ComponentInfo{com.android.android/com.android.android.conversation.a.PRofile}: 
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: 
       Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.android.android.util.view.CustomEditText
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
                                                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.android.android.util.view.CustomEditText
                                                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class com.android.android.util.view.CustomEditText
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

Comment: why do you have multiple options in `inputType` in your style ?

Comment: I need all of them :)

Comment: and use of emojiSize have you tried with removing it? Because I think default edittext class has no attribute like this

Comment: EmojiEditText supports emojis

Comment: show `CustomEditText `

Comment: I have tried to remove emojiSize and still error was continued @UmarHussain

Comment: let me know if you remove `style="@style/ComposeEditText"` then ?

Comment: if I remove style, it is running but I want to add style

Comment: I have tried to remove <item name="android:autoText">true</item> <item name="android:inputType">textAutoCorrect|textCapSentences|te‌​xtMultiLine</item> and still error was continued @IntelliJ Amiya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just remove "@style/" and it is solved. Thank you for your help

instead of

```
<style name="ComposeEditText" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
```

use

```
 <style name="ComposeEditText" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your `CustomEditText` which is `EmojiEditText`, please try to set the `parent` of your style to EmojiEditText's style. I think the issue is your style is inheriting from wrong style